# issue with convert number in format

Tags: jquery, format

I want to convert my number in XXXXX-XXXX-XX format and I am trying using [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6rCN/5/) for that but with which changes I can get XXXXX-XXXX-XX format.

```js
    var format = function(num){
    var str = num.toString().replace("$", ""), parts = false, output = [], i = 1, formatted = null;
    if(str.indexOf(".") > 0) {
        parts = str.split(".");
        str = parts[0];
    }
    str = str.split("").reverse();
    for(var j = 0, len = str.length; j < len; j++) {
        if(str[j] != ",") {
            output.push(str[j]);
            if(i%4 == 0 && j < (len - 1)) {
                output.push(",");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    formatted = output.reverse().join("");
    return("$" + formatted + ((parts) ? "." + parts[1].substr(0, 2) : ""));
};
$(function(){
    $("#currency").keyup(function(e){
        $(this).val(format($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

also but it is also not working.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve - can you include some before/after examples?

Comment: @freedomn-m when I type number in my input box I want to make that number in XXXXX-XXXX-XX formate

Comment: I don't know what "XXXXX-XXXX-XX format" means, hence asking for *examples*, simply reiterating what you've already stated does not help to clarify.  What does `1` format as?  `1.23`?  `100`?  etc

Comment: Please define the problem in better terms. What is your input and what is your output, with examples(the better). Explain why your solution doesnt work and define with what part are you struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments that ask for you to explain your code a bit better are most likely because you have alot of redundancies in your format function that make no sense for your specific problem. (Maybe its a copied code that you tried to adjust to your needs )

Given you want to input a string of the format `XXXXXXXXXX` and automatically format it to `XXXXX-XXXXX-XX`, you would need to limit the number of characters to `10` and insert a `-` after every 4th character.

Also consider to limit the characters that are allowed in your string. e.g. to only numbers or only numbers + A-Za-z depending on your needs, if you want to prevent the use of unwanted characters like `,` or `@`

```js
function format( val ) {
    let num = val.replace(/\-/g, '').split('');
  let output = "";
  let numPos = 1;
  let maxChars = 10;
  for(var i = 0; i < num.length && i < maxChars; i++) {
    output += num[i];
    if(numPos%4 == 0 && i < (num.length - 1)) {
      output += "-";
    }
    numPos++;
  }
  return output;
}

$('input').on('input', function() {
    $(this).val( format( $(this).val() ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```